# Amazon Sagemaker Runs doesn't show any run with the new update

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

So I think the Sagemaker UI was updated very recently this week, and now I can't find any of my previous "runs" / "trials" / "jobs"...

When I go to home - Experiments, I can see the names of two experiments I have done in the past, but when I click on it, it just says "No runs / You don't have any runs". Not only did I have a bunch of runs / jobs (not sure if the term changed), but when I try to launch another one with my previously working script, it runs well (and saves itself well on S3) but doesn't show.

Anyone has the same problem ? Where should I turn to help ?

Answer (score 0):

As part of those changes, automatically generated runs (previously called "trial components") are hidden by default.

On the "Runs" table for your experiment, click the cog icon in the upper right and enable "Show jobs". This will display any automatically generated runs in the table.